# Does shutil.copy verify?

Tags: python, copy

The shutil.copy-command in Python has a return value: It "returns the path to the newly created file". Does that mean, that the copied file was verified?
Greetings, Strawk

Comment: What sort of verification did you have in mind? Saying that a file is verified doesn't make sense. You can verify things *about* a file.

Comment: What level of verification is needed? shutil.copy closes the file and returns the name it used to open it. The file could have been moved, renamed or unlinked (on linux systems) after the open and shutil wouldn't know.

Comment: "What sort of verification did you have in mind?" I mean a physical check whether copy operation worked fine.

Comment: @Strawk - Closing the file guarantees that the data made it to the operating system cache, not the physical disk so something like a power loss or drive failure is still possible. But operating systems are generally good at getting the right stuff to disk in the right order. shutil just assumes it all works. You could do your own checksumming and verify later by reopening file.

Answer (score 0):

`shutil.copy` does not verify the copy. It generates a file name, opens source and destination, copies the data and closes the file. It does not verify the file name after the write - and it shouldn't. It perfectly legal for some entity to move an open file without affecting existing readers and writers.

It closes the file which flushes the data to the operating system's file system cache but does not verify that the file was written to disk. A power failure would cause data loss.

It also does not reread the data to make sure that the correct bytes were written. The destination is not opened exclusive so its technically possible for some other process to open and write the same file. That is a remote possibility of course. Generally its the operating system's job to make sure the correct bits are written.